# i am having issues with what is stored in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following code and I am confused as to why does the compiler show more elements than array size.

```
# include <iostream>
using name space std;

int main() 
{
    int arr[]={1,2,34,5};

    for(int i=0; arr[i]; i++)
    {
         cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `i o stream` spaced out like that? How does this compile? In programming every little character counts, so do keep an eye out for even the most minor of mistakes. These things can change the meaning of your code in unpredictable and profound ways.

Comment: How can you compile this program ? Not  `# include < i o stream >`. It will be `#include < iostream >`. Not  `c out<<arr[i]<<end l;`. It will be `cout<<arr[i]<<endl;`. Then you can compile this program and will find error.

Comment: Read up on for loops and their termination condition. For this to work correctly, your array would need to be terminated with a 0. As it is, you read beyond `are until you reach a 0 or your program crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're walking off the end of the array because your conditions here are "element has non-zero value" rather than "index is not at end of array".

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
```

I'd strongly advise you to use the Standard Library containers for problems like this, such as `std::vector`, as then you can use simple iterators instead. Those make it harder to trip up like this because there's things like [`for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) which follow simple patterns using iterators.

Comment: Or `for (auto x : arr) ...`

Comment: @juanchopanza Another great reason to use the Standard Library. Newer compilers support that and it's a pleasure to use.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
for(int i=0;arr[i];i++)
```

is equivalent to

```
for(int i=0;arr[i] != 0;i++)
```

You have initialized `arr` such that all the elements of the array within the valid array indices are non-zero. Hence, the only way `arr[i] != 0` will be `true` is if `arr` is accessed using an out-of-bounds index. However, that is cause for undefined behavior, which is what you are seeing in your program.

If you have access to a C++11 compiler, use the range-`for` loop to access all the elements of the array.

```
for ( auto el : arr )
{
   // Use el
}
```

If you don't have access to a C++11 compiler, use the size of the array to break the loop before you access the array out of bounds.

```
size_t size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i )
{
   int el = arr[i];
   // Use el
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,2,34,5};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```